# C# Printing A Form

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I'm new to c#, so I hope this doesn't sound/look stupid.

I'm having an issue while printing. I can't seem to get my form to print on the full size of a regular piece of paper. It's printing in landscape, the height fits, but my width goes off the page. Here is the code I'm working with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
}

private void printPreviewDialog1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintPreviewDialog _PrintPreview = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    _PrintPreview.Document = printDocument1;
    ((Form)_PrintPreview).WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    _PrintPreview.ShowDialog();
}

private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveAsBitmap(this, @"img\1.bmp");
    CaptureScreen();
    printDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
    printDocument1.Print();
}
```

Comment: Please don't delete and repost questions.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the papersize in the printOption : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691030(v=vs.71).aspx

Hope this can help you!